# looping json data returned from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I need to loop through the json object returned from my controller.

My controller code

```
    public ActionResult GetJobs()
    {
        var jobs = new JobConfig().getJobs(User.Identity.Name);

        return Json(jobs.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

My javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#search').click(function () {


        $.when(
            getUser(), //Get User Details
            getJobs()//Get Jobs
          ).then(process);

    });

});

function getUser() {

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ManageUsers/GetUser',
        data: { UserName: $('#txtUser').val() },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function getJobs() {

      return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ManageUsers/GetJobs',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function process(user,jobs) {

    //Show the user here

    if (user[0].Name != null) {


        var list = '<p> User : ' + user[0].Name + '<br/>';
        list += 'Email : ' + user[0].Email + '<br/>';
        list += 'Role : ' + user[0].Role + '<br/>';
        list += 'UserData : ' + user[0].UserData;
        list += '</p><br/>';


        alert(jobs.length);

        $('#user').empty();
        $('#user').append(list);



    }
    else {
        $('#user').empty();
        $('#user').append('User not exists');
    }
}
```

alert(jobs.length) says the length is 3 because the job object looks like this

```
jobs: Array[3]
0: Array[1]
1: "success"
2: Object
```

But I am only concerned with the 0 element.

I think its the way result is returned when using return $.ajax function.

Any thoughts on just getting the 1 st element from the jobs array?

Regards,

Sab

Comment: Can you include a sample of the json string returned from your action result?

Comment: @Jesse this is what i got [{"JobId":"ArtListLoad","JobDesc":"GOLD Article List Load","JobFilePrefix":null,"JobFileSrcDir":null,"JobFileDataDir":null,"JobFileExtension":null,"JobFileDataRange":null,"JobScript":null}]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var someReturnedData = [{"JobId":"ArtListLoad","JobDesc":"GOLD Article List Load","JobFilePrefix":null,"JobFileSrcDir":null,"JobFileDataDir":null,"JobFileEx‌​tension":null,"JobFileDataRange":null,"JobScript":null}]
```

Given a JSON data object as per your example that has returned from you action result you can access the first element with:

```
someReturnedData[0]
```

Meaning if you wanted to "JobId" you could access it with:

```
someReturnedData[0].JobId
```

EDIT:

As per you comment, you can modify your GetJobs function to include a success handler. Do what ever processing you require and then return that object to your process function. Maybe something like this:

```
function getJobs() {

    var jobs;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ManageUsers/GetJobs',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           jobs = data[0];
        }
    });

    return jobs;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the json data from the responseText property of the json object.How will I extract the responseText property into a var?If you have any example

Comment: thanks for replying.I have left work now so can't test it now.Will check it as the first thing tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: i used it as you suggested in the get jobs method and it did not work.But when I used it in process method it worked.Thanks for helping out